# C++ pointer arithmetic in a loop and memory management?

Tags: c++

I am getting started with C++. I wanted to understand the different
outputs while playing around with this snippet of code.

```
int main()
{
    int i = 3;
    int *ptr = &i; //stores address of the i
    while(*(ptr)--) //the same as i--
    {
        cout << *ptr << endl;
    }
}
```

When I run this code I understand that the deferenced value
of ptr, which is "i", gets 1 subtracted from it and the loop exits
when "i" equals 0. But when I use **while(*ptr--)** instead of **while(*(ptr)--)** I get a list of random integers which eventually go down to 0 and the loop breaks.

To my understanding when I use ***ptr--** I am subtracting a byte(size of one int) from the initial address of &i(*ptr) with each loop. But why does the program terminate eventually? No matter what the value of "i" is, the program prints 23 random numbers with the last one being 0 and the loop exits. Should I not get an overflow error since the program runs out of memory?

However, when I use **while(ptr--)** the program does go into an infinite loop.
What exactly is happening?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Just because a loop is long doesn't mean it is infinite.

Comment: `*ptr--` and `*(ptr)--` are exactly the same...

Answer (score 2):

`(ptr)` is the same as `ptr`, thus `(ptr)--` is the same as `ptr--`.

`*ptr--` IS NOT the same as `i--` !

You are applying `operator--` to the *right side* of the pointer.  The suffix/postfix `operator--` has a [higher precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than `operator*`.  So, `*ptr--` is the same as `*(ptr--)`, not `(*ptr)--` like you are expecting.

IOW, `ptr--` gets evaluated first, which returns a *copy of the current pointer* and then **decrements the pointer**, and then you are dereferencing the *copied pointer* to retrieve the value that was *previously* being pointing at.

That is why you are seeing garbage - you are decrementing the pointer into memory that does not belong to you.

To simply decrement the `int` and not the pointer, use `(*ptr)--` instead.  IOW, dereference the pointer first, then decrement the value being pointed at, eg:

```
int main()
{
    int i = 3;
    int *ptr = &i; //stores address of the i
    while((*ptr)--) //the same as i--
    {
        cout << *ptr << endl;
    }
}
```

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/V1GTe5)

Parenthesis and operator precedence matter!

Comment: Albeit possibly over-done, anecdotally having just had to deal with a firmware bug from a prior dev: use parenthesis to make it absolutely clear to both the reader and the compiler, what it is you intend to do.